# Depending on apache_beam from a bazel project

Tags: apache-beam, bazel

I am creating a bazel python project which depends on apache_beam sdk. In the WORKSPACE file of my project, I have downloaded apache_beam zip file via http_archive.

Whenever I am trying to access apache_beam.testing sub-package in my project, I am getting an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apache_beam.testing'
```

`import apache_beam` is working fine though.

```
WORKSPACE:

http_archive(
    name = "apache_beam",
    urls = ["https://github.com/apache/beam/archive/master.zip"],
    strip_prefix = 'beam-master/sdks/python',
    build_file = str(Label("//third_party:apache_beam.BUILD")),
)



apache_beam.BUILD:

py_library(
    name = "apache_beam",
    srcs = glob(["apache_beam/**/*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)



project's BUILD file:

py_test(
    name = "project",
    srcs = ["project.py"],
    deps = [
        "@apache_beam//:apache_beam",
    ],



project.py file:

from apache_beam.testing import util
```

Answer (score 0):

In `apache_beam.BUILD`, you need to set the `imports` attribute:

```
py_library(
    name = "apache_beam",
    srcs = glob(["apache_beam/**/*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    imports = "apache_beam",
)
```